# How to POST json to the Wufoo Entries API?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, wufoo

The current documentation is a little lacking on how exactly to submit forms via Ajax. There is [The Entries POST API](http://help.wufoo.com/articles/en_US/SurveyMonkeyArticleType/The-Entries-POST-API) but it talks only about xml, and doesn't even show an example payload.

I see that Wufoo has a half-built, abandoned jQuery plugin [wufoo/Wufoo-jQuery-API-Wrapper](https://github.com/wufoo/Wufoo-jQuery-API-Wrapper) which seems to do little more than wrap `$.get` and format errors a bit. POST is listed as a "todo".

I've tried hitting the API with things like:

```
{
  "Field1": "first",
  "Field2": "last",
  "Field3": "email@example.com",
  "Field4": "test messsage",
}
```

And based on the line "This call would contain POST parameters in name/value pairs" and the example `postAuthenticated(array('Field1' => 'Frank'));` I tried just sending an array of arrays.

```
[
  ['Field1', 'first'],
  ['Field2', 'last'],
  ['Field3', 'email@example.com'],
  ['Field4', 'test messsage']
]
```

But since those are obviously the wrong format, I always get the following in response.

```
{
    "Success": 0,
    "ErrorText": "Errors have been <b>highlighted</b> below.",
    "FieldErrors": [
        {
            "ID": "Field3",
            "ErrorText": "This field is required. Please enter a value."
        },
        {
            "ID": "Field4",
            "ErrorText": "This field is required. Please enter a value."
        }
    ]
}
```

Does anyone have any idea how to format these requests? Maybe someone with more experience with CurlService could interpret it from their example, but I can't make heads or tails of that documentation, nor find any examples online.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I should have known. The service doesn't *accept* json, it only *replies* in json. Submitting a regular urlencoded form body works.

Comment: Thank you for saving me a tonne of time. The documentation is very unclear about this limitation IMO.

Comment: What are you doing in order to make the POST request? I am trying but the only way I could connect with the basic auth is with JSONP which does not allow me to send a POST request but a GET request. How did you handle auth?

Comment: No auth, just posting new entries from the front-end.

Comment: Wow, thank you! I was stuck on this for hours as well, trying to POST json to their api. Strange, because I was getting a successful reply, even though my json request body was never accepted.

Comment: So are POST requests not possible using JavaScript? I'm using Google Apps Script and can't get either GET or POSTs to work as it's returning a 401 as I don't know how to authenticate.